# Change Order of scrape data in scrapy python

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, fifo, lifo

I am using scrapy to scrape data from a website .And I am getting data in this format.
e.g
{
'Date': '03/06/2020',
'LTV': '90',
}
{
'Date': '03/06/2020',
'LTV': '80',
}

{
'Date': '03/06/2020',
'LTV': '70',
}
...I want to change this Sequence. I want LTV ->70 , 80, 90, in this sequence. First come LTV 70 array then 80 and So on.
Note : I am using Scrapy framework.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy outputs item in parsing order by design. You cannot rely on them being in a specific order.

If you want to sort output items in a specific way, you should do one of the following:

- Use a custom script after running Scrapy to sort the items in the output file.
- Write a custom [item exporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html) that sorts the items in the output file from its [`finish_exporting()`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.exporters.BaseItemExporter.finish_exporting) method